# HeapWorker Android performance

Tags: android, performance, dalvik

```
[ 01-01 08:29:02.954 1511:0x5e7 E/dalvikvm ]
HeapWorker is wedged: 10330ms spent inside Landroid/content/ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner;.finalize()V
[ 01-01 08:29:02.954 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
DALVIK THREADS:    
[ 01-01 08:29:02.954 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
"main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE    
[ 01-01 08:29:02.954 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x400258c8 self=0xcd98
[ 01-01 08:29:02.954 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
  | sysTid=1511 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345021912
[ 01-01 08:29:02.977 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:Note: 0000662)
[ 01-01 08:29:02.977 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
  at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:664)
[ 01-01 08:29:02.977 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
  at java.io.File.join(File.java:264)
[ 01-01 08:29:02.977 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:175)
[ 01-01 08:29:02.977 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:142)
[ 01-01 08:29:02.977 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
  at java.io.File.filenamesToFiles(File.java:1082)
[ 01-01 08:29:02.977 1511:0x5e7 I/dalvikvm ]
  at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1008)
```

How to resolve this issue?

I know the root cause is to much temporary variables be created.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at the stack trace for the wrong thread.

The problem is that a finalizer took more than 10 seconds to complete, so the VM assumed it was deadlocked and aborted to cause the app to restart.  In this case, the stalled function is android.content.ContentResolver.CursorWrapperInner.finalize().

There should be a stack trace for the HeapWorker thread nearby.

Comment: `HeapWorker is wedged: 33299ms spent inside Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteCompiledSql;.finalize()V` Can nested sqlite transactions cause this to happen?

Comment: What is finalizer BTW?

Comment: Also this is only happening on Emulator working fine on my Nexus 4.

Comment: You probably need to update your emulator -- Dalvik hasn't had a HeapWorker thread for a couple of years. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()

Comment: `art WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 15.321ms for cause HeapTrim` What does that means is it warning or normal log?

Comment: I have no experience with Art, so I'm afraid I can't help you with that one.

Comment: No worries any way thanks mate for sharing some valuable info though.